# Code efficiency in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, performance

I am working with a treeview that contains nodes from a directory, where the lowest node is a piece of text from a file. I would like to be able to get that node, and get it's filename, and ive done so in the following line of code, but is there a nicer way of doing this? I want it to be as efficient as possible, and i'm wondering if its better to just create an integer to store the index number, rather than calculating it in the index itself. I know if the integer variable is created i will have to do that calculation anyway...

(tVSNodes is a list of treenodes)

TL:DR - is there a more efficient(faster execution) way of doing this?

```
string filename = tVSNodes[0].FullPath.Split('\\')[(tVSNodes[0].FullPath.Split('\\').Count()-2)];
```

Comment: If this is the best way, let me know, I'm just not sure if i should leave it like that or break it all apart.

Comment: How are you defining efficiency? Speed of execution? Readability? Something else?

Comment: @Mac - Do you have reason to believe that the execution could be improved.  Have you determine how quick your code is (i.e. O(n)...Log(n)...Log(n^2)...ect ) is exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm not sure how i would do that. I know the types of speeds you listed, but i dont know how i would calculate it without running it many many times..

Comment: Can you use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) static methods? You're talking about trees but you seem to just split a string here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to get the text of the parent node.

```
if (tVSNodes[0].Parent == null)
     return;  // handle appropriately

string fileName = tVSNodes[0].Parent.Text;
```

Comment: I cant believe i didn't think of this. Its MUCH simpler. Thanks!